# Sealing Off Gravity Pipe from Crawl Space

Tags: drainage, crawlspace

I currently have a 6" clay pipe for eliminating water from my crawlspace.  The pipe exits my crawlspace about a foot from a corner wall, travels 15', and opens to air in a ditch (for now).  It is about 1.5-2' down from the crawlspace soil.

Due to some work being performed on my property, the ditch where the gravity discharge pipe currently exits will be covered up (about 3' of soil).  There is no easy way to get around that.  Preparing for this, I hired some folks to install a sump pump to catch water and pump it out.  We've had a rain or two since the installation, and it worked beautifully.

Now, because the pipe exit was too close to the concrete footers of the house, the sump basin had to be installed out of the main drainage trench path.  Therefore, when I seal the pipe from the inside, the current path the interior trenches follow will be directly into my footers. That cannot be good...

While the sump is definitely doing its job, it needs the full burden of ALL of the water that should be exiting my crawlspace.  How would you all recommend I divert this water into the sump and not against my footers.  Also, is there any particular way you would recommend I seal off the current gravity pipe?  Concrete? Clay? Some kind of plug handmade from foam-board and spray foam?